# (Windows Server 2016) Active Directory OU Policy

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2016, group-policy

I was wondering what is the best way to implement a policy on OU's for a domain controller.

Essentially I would like to make a policy on an OU so that as soon as a user is added to that OU or a new user is created under this OU it will set the specified permissions needed to that person.

Anyone got any ideas?

TIA.

Comment: Stack Overflow is really just for programming questions. This question is better suited for [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com), which is for server-administration questions. You will probably have better success asking the question there.

Comment: Great thanks, will do ill take it over there.

Answer (score 0):

That is what GPO is used for, you can create GP's and then link them to the OU you want them apply to in AD.